# PIC18F OSCCON Register Requied if I define OSC = INTIO1?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, pic18

New to microcontrollers, need to wrap my head around this basic thing:

So, I'm trying to program a PIC18F4520, I know I can set an external clock using `#define OSC = HS` and connecting the crystal between the required pins. I have a doubt that is, if I define the Oscillator requirement as `#define OSC = INTIO2`
BaSically this:

```
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config OSC=INTIO1                //HERE!!
#pragma config PWRT=OFF
#pragma config WDT=OFF
#pragma config DEBUG=OFF, LVP=OFF

void delay(int);

void main(void) {

return;
}
```

Do I need to set the OSCCON register and the CONFIG1 register?

Comment: if you are using internal oscillator then its better to initialize OSCCON

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you to go inside the MPLAB X Software to **Window -> PIC Memory Views -> Configuration Bits**. This will show you a new window to help you to configure properly your fuses, in this case the PIC18F4520 will show you the **CONFIG1H** register, inside is the **OSC** field, you can choose the oscillator right here with the available options.

However, you still need to tell what oscillator are you using to the microcontroller. To do this part you will need to read the [PIC18F4520 Datasheet](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC18F4520) and look for the Table of Contents page (Page 6), you will see the Oscillator Configurations (Page 23 according with the Datasheet), there you have all the information required to setup the External Oscillator that you want to use properly. I hope this could solve your issues.